# Programmatically Determine If An Excel File (.xls) Contains Macros

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, ms-office, digital-certificate

Is there any way to programmatically determine if an .xls contains macros, without actually opening it in Excel?

Also are there any methods to examine which certificate (including timestamp cert) these macros are signed with? Again without using Excel.

I'm wondering in particular if there are any strings that always show up in the raw data of an Excel file when macros are present.

Comment: This would be for an XLS file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can open the .xls file as a compound document file and check whether is contains a VBA folder and streams containing VBA code.

Sample code is available in this CodeProject article:

> **[Another OLE Doc Viewer but with editing facility](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/Another_OLE_Doc_Viewer.aspx)**

The certificate information is stored in the *DocumentSummaryInformation* stream. If you want to read out the information from there you should dig into the file format specifications available from Microsoft:

> [[MS-OSHARED]: Office Common Data Types and Objects Structure Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313156%28office.12%29.aspx)
>
> [[MS-OFFCRYPTO]: Office Document Cryptography Structure Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313071%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's even better than I expected, I had no idea the file formats were publically available!

Answer (score 0):

An xls file containing a macro should contain a string looking something like

```
Keyboard Shortcut:
```

Don't know if this is a surefire solution though