# Verifiy if an xls file contains VBA macros without opening it in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, binary, ole

I have a big set of `.xls` (Excel 97-2003 Workbook) files. A few of them contain VBA macros inside, I would like to find a way to filter them out automatically without opening them one by one in MS Excel.

There is an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006328/programmatically-determine-if-an-excel-file-xls-contains-macros) which is similar to my question, I have downloaded the [OLE Doc viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7453/Another-OLE-Doc-Viewer-but-with-editing-facility), but cannot open the .zip file, it seems that it is out of date...

Does anyone know if there is any API or tool to check if an `.xls` file contains VBA macros without opening it in MS Excel? In the first place, I don't bother to know the content of the macros.

PS: for a `.xlsx` or `.xlsm` file, we can change their file extension to `.zip` which contain some `.xml` files and eventually `vbaProject.bin` for VBA macros. However, this approach does not work for `.xls` file, renaming it does not make a valid `.zip`file.

Comment: Would you consider a solution that opens them automatically ? A VBA macro can do the job.

Comment: At this stage, I don't consider this option... Thank you...

Comment: The xls file format is documented ; reference is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944649(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Ways to pars xml files without Excel have been treated on SO [see here : python approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python) and [here : java/lua approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120582/how-to-parse-a-xls-file-known-languages-python-java-lua)

Comment: There are also [ways](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/169f2398-f8af-4b22-b566-6b002cbd6515/vbscript-read-from-excelfile-but-now-without-excel-installation-on-a-server) to do this using vbscript ... but that will effectively open the file in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/) solution I've cooked for you:

It depends only on the OleFileIO_PL module which is availble [from the project page](https://bitbucket.org/decalage/olefileio_pl/downloads)
The good thing with OleFile parser is that it is not aware of the "excel-specific" contents of the file ; it only knows the higher level "OLE storage". So it is quick in analyzing the file, and there is no risk that a potentially harmful macro would execute.

```
import OleFileIO_PL
import argparse

if __name__=='__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Determine if an Excel 97-2007 file contains macros.', epilog='Will exit successfully (0) only if provided file is a valid excel file containing macros.')
    parser.add_argument('filename', help="file name to analyse")
    args=parser.parse_args()

    # Test if a file is an OLE container:
    if (not OleFileIO_PL.isOleFile(args.filename)):
        exit("This document is not a valid OLE document.")

    # Open an OLE file:
    ole = OleFileIO_PL.OleFileIO(args.filename)

    # Test if known streams/storages exist:
    if (not ole.exists('workbook')):
        exit("This document is not a valid Excel 97-2007 document.")

    # Test if VBA specific streams exist:
    if (not ole.exists('_VBA_PROJECT_CUR')):
        exit("This document does not contain VBA macros.")

    print("Valid Excel 97-2007 workbook WITH macros")
```

I tested it on a couple of files with success. Let me know if it's suitable for you